# Why is the parameter not saved in cookies?

Tags: java, spring-boot, internationalization

I generated my code as in the example, but unfortunately, when switching between pages, the parameter is not saved in the browser cookies. Why is this parameter not there?

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
    public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver()  {
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver= new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setCookieDomain("myAppLocaleCookie");
        // 60 minutes 
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(60*60); 
        return resolver;
    } 

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource getMessageResource()  {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageResource= new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        // Read i18n/messages_xxx.properties file.
        // For example: i18n/messages_en.properties
        messageResource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
        messageResource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageResource;
    }
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");


        registry.addInterceptor(localeInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/*");
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't set the `cookieDomain`... I highly doubt that that is your domain, if the domain doesn't match the actual domain (probably `localhost` when testing) the cookie won't be send to the server. Also the `addPathPatterns` should be `/**` to match every level, currently it matches single level deep, this is also the default so I would suggest to remove `addPathPatterns`.

Comment: @M. Deinum Good. I delete .addPathPatterns ("/ *"); Would you like to get me to set localhost?

Comment: Don't set anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed comment СookieDomain:

```
@Bean(name = "localeResolver")
    public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver()  {
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver= new CookieLocaleResolver();
        //resolver.setCookieDomain("myAppLocaleCookie");
        // 60 minutes 
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(60*60); 
        return resolver;
    }
```